# How to search with phone no. in yelp api v2?

Tags: yelp

I am newly working with yelp api. here I see that using phone number there is no search option in yelp 2.

I want to is any other way to search with phone number in yelp v2 that I have not noticed.

Thanks

Comment: What have tried yet , I can help if you can show us what is the problem.

Comment: I am not started coding. I have just studied the api documentation, but I did not find how to search with phone. But I want to search with phone.I want to know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

On the 1.0 API (http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/phone_api)
you are able to do it. 
I'd suspect you can on the 2.0 too I'd try it out. 
 here is what they say: 
`http://api.yelp.com/phone_search?phone=1234567890&ywsid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

I'd try on api 2.0
`http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?phone_search=XXXXXXXXXX` 
or 
`http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?phone=XXXXXXXXXX` 
And see if it works.

 To make the answer short, **YES** you can but only for sure on the 1.0 API and **MAYBE** on the 2.0

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand ( not yet fully checked ) you should use the `term` and it will mach the business to the telephone
like

```
http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?term=XXXXXXXXXX
```

XXXXXXX = phone number

Answer (score 0):

its actually:

```
https://api.yelp.com/v2/phone_search?phone=+15555555555
```

Here is the reference:
https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/phone_search